# Where can we find the Selenium version compatible versions of GeckoDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Earlier I used this method to add gecko driver:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/home/boo/Desktop/java/geckodriver-v0.20.1-linux64/geckodriver");
```

but the new update (https://selenium.dev/)

https://selenium.org/ --> https://selenium.dev/

Now it redirects so I have no idea how can I download , when I download it saves as .nupke I download from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver/)

```
selenium.webdriver.geckodriver.0.26.0.nupkg
```

How can I use this .nupkg?

And there is other 4 method available

1. package-manager
2. dotnet-cli
3. package-reference
4. paket-cli

I'm using Java Maven for automation in those 4. Which one I have to choose and how can i setup?

PS: earlier I downloaded zip file and extracted and used it

Comment: Download it from github https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.26.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and *GeckoDriver* are seperately maintained and published. You can download the required version of *GeckoDriver* from [**Releases - mozilla/geckodriver**](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) page.